# Working directory different than current file directory?

Tags: working-directory

I saw something strange happen today.
I was in directory `/some/path/` and opened a file with `vim file.html`.

I then did :pwd in vim and it gave me `/some/other/path`. What could cause this to happen?

EDIT: `:verbose set autochdir?` outputs `noautochdir`

EDIT2: putting `set autochdir` in `~/.vimrc` doesn't solve it.

I tried this:

1. `cd /dir1/`
2. `vim dir2/newfile`
3. `:pwd` -> `/dir1/`
4. `cd /dir1/dir2/`
5. `vim newfile`
6. `:pwd` -> `/dir1/dir2/`

This is the behavious I expect (`:pwd` returning the directory in which I launched vim) so I don't understand why for one particular file it doesn't work like that.

<del>I figured it must be somehow caused by</del> It is definitely caused by these [lines](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_views_automatic) in `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufWinLeave * mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter * silent loadview
```

I deleted my `~/.vimrc` and `:pwd` returned the correct directory.

After I restored it, the situation reverted to the original problem.
I still don't understand how it happenned, I can't recreate the issue.

Comment: Please add the output of `:verbose set autochdir?` to the question.

Comment: this gave me no output EDIT: my bad, forgot `?`

Comment: Hmm... `mkview` stores a lot of stuff, not just folds. It mentions [`'sessionoptions'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27sessionoptions%27) in the documentation and `sessionoptions` has a `curdir` option. This *might* be what's causing it, but I'm not sure. You could try taking `curdir` out of `sessionoptions` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

As of vim8, `mkview` by default stores current directory for every buffer. You can find `lcd <path>` lines inside your views.

To disable this: `set viewoptions-=curdir`

Answer (score 2):

In your `vimrc` put `set autochdir` and your path will always follow your current file. Otherwise vim will usually stay in either your home directory or in the first file you edited without you explicitly telling it to change with `cd`.

See [`:help 'autochdir'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27autochdir%27) for more info.

Comment: please see my edits